# Jquery based image accordian plugin

Tags: plugins, jquery

I found a image accorian menu plugin based on mootools farework. Please suggest if any based on jquery framework.

Comment: Have you tried any of the numerous scripts that can be found by googling for **jquery** and **accordian**? jQuery UI Accordian is one of several possibilities.

Comment: of course i hadnt thats why i asked. Moreover i dont know basic of jquery. SO its implementation would be very difficult to me. So i was searching for wordpress plugin which can be installed and use

Comment: A quick google turnt this up: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/accordion-image-menu/ ... demo here: http://web-argument.com/accordion-image-menu-v-20/ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @t31os. This is what i was looking for:

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/accordion-image-menu/

Answer (score 1):

Try the one from jQuery UI